# How accept react-dropzone geojson files

Tags: reactjs, geojson, react-dropzone

i'm using react-dropzone plugin for my react app where upload files.

here is my problem that uploader not accept .geojson files.

i tried : `accept="application/*"` , `accept="application/vnd.geo+json"`, and many things but not worked.

Is there anyway to do it ?

Comment: did you try accept=".geojson"?

Comment: yes i tried this too i tried all i think :)

Comment: the main problem that dropzone doesn't support files without mime type

Comment: With too :) mime types using for geojson application/geo+json,  application/vnd.geo+json i tried all of them

Comment: I just tried to upload .geojson file (which I generated there http://geojson.io/#map=3/38.75/11.95) and it's works https://react-dropzone.js.org/

Comment: which mimes you passed to accept prop ?

Comment: https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/issues/276#issuecomment-432628384

Answer (score 0):

you probably has this issue sorted now, but here's the solution I found:

```
accept: {
  'application/json': ['.json'], // you need to specify into this array the extensions you want to accept
},
```

You can check this page for more context:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/showOpenFilePicker

and also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types

Cheers!